# Why is "if" statement causes "while" loop to freeze the browser?

Tags: php, if-statement, browser, while-loop, crash

I have somewhat of an interesting issue. After adding an *if* statement to my *while loop* with-in PHP function, my (Chrome) browser window running the site would not respond. I've verified that it's an *if* statement causing the issue by commenting it out. Everything loads great with an *if* statements commented out.

Results are the same with both loops.

```
function disp_editForm($id, $day, $month, $year, $type, $content) {
$d_count = 0;
$m_count = 0;

echo '<select name="editDay" id="editDay" onchange="" size="1">';
while($d_count<31) {
$d_count++;
if($d_count=$day) { $dSelected = "selected"; } // Select value in the drop box
echo '<option value="'.$d_count.'"'.$dSelected.'>'.$d_count.'</option>';
} // End Day While Loop
echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="editMonth" id="editMonth" onchange="" size="1">';
while($m_count<12) {
$m_count++;
if($m_count=$month) { $mSelected = "selected"; } // Select value in the drop box
echo '<option value="'.$m_count.'"'.$mSelected.'>';
mConvert($m_count); // Convert month number into a word
echo '</option>';
} // End Month While Loop
echo '</select>';
```

}

Comment: You do an assignment in your if statements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($d_count=$day) { $dSelected = "selected"; }
if($m_count=$month) { $mSelected = "selected"; }
```

should be

```
if($d_count==$day) { $dSelected = "selected"; }
if($m_count==$month) { $mSelected = "selected"; }
```

You're doing an assignment(`=`) here rather than an equality comparison(`==`).

Answer (score 2):

Use equality comparison Operator `==` instead of `=`

```
f($d_count==$day) { $dSelected = "selected"; }
if($m_count==$month) { $mSelected = "selected"; }
```